# Would Franz Joseph I (emperor of Austria 1848-1916) protect a minority hated by others or would he help assimilate them?

Tags: alternate-history, history

My world has a conflict involving Franz Joseph and a hated minority inside his empire. The Ottoman's want control over them, and I'm not sure whether he would protect them for power, protect them because he believes they don't deserve it, or give them away. Does anyone have any help to give?

Comment: Who are they? What is their role in the empire? Where do they live? Is it a strategical place for the empire? And last... can you narrow your problem to something less opinion based?

Comment: "The Ottomans want control" -- that means that the minority in question is the Bosnians. Bosnia and Herzegovina was in Cisleithania, so Franz Joseph at least had the power (if not the inclination) to help. But then Bosnians were not particularly hated, except for their occasional terrorist tendencies, e.g., the assassination of Sarajevo which started WW1. Please bear in mind that by the time of Franz Joseph the Ottoman Empire was in dire straits and fighting for its survival; their days of power were long gone.

Comment: @AlexP Its not the Bosnians. They're a society I created and they're treated almost as bad as Jews were during World War II.

Comment: @user16622 I don't think we can answer this question without more information about the 'hated' group. Its is borderline opinion based to judge Franz Joseph's intentions towards an existing group, but definitely opinion based to judge his intent to an imaginary one.

Answer (score 7):

Franz Joseph was emperor *of Austria* and *king* of Hungary. There was no such thing as an emperor of [Austria-Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria-Hungary). The Empire ("[Cisleithania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisleithania)" in the press of the time) and the Kingdom ("[Transleithania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lands_of_the_Crown_of_Saint_Stephen)") functioned pretty much as separate states in a sort of loose confederacy. The few common institutions of Austria and Hungary carried the delicious attribute "k.u.k." -- *kaiserlich und königlich*, Imperial and Royal; those were the Imperial and Royal Ministry of Exterior, the Imperial and Royal Ministry of War and the Imperial and Royal Army. There was no joint parliament, and, decisively, no joint budget.

In the Dual Monarchy *everybody* was a minority, except of course the Austrians and the Hungarians. Croats, Czechs, Romanians, Ruthenians, Slovenes, Slovaks, etc. were minorities; and Jews, of course -- with the difference that assimilated Jews could claim Austrian or Hungarian status. Actually the Austrians and Hungarians were minorities too, numerically, but they had the upper hand in their respective countries (the Empire of Austria and the Kingdom of Hungary) and therefore did not think of themselves as minorities.

The status of minorities was quite different in the Empire and in the Kingdom, with the Hungarian part being perceived as being significantly more oppressive and quite intent on assimilating their minorities; see [Magyarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magyarization). Franz Joseph himself was pretty much uninterested in the problems of minorities, but then he did nothing actually oppressive; as far as he was concerned the Empire and the Kingdom were multi-ethnic states, and that was a good thing, or at least not a bad thing; he tried to live to the motto of his [House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Lorraine), *"Viribus unitis"*, that is, "with joint forces".

The actual power of the crown in Hungary was much smaller than in Austria; so if you want to make Franz Joseph take care of some minority you should really place it in Cisleithania, because in Transleithania there was little he could do directly; he would have to work through the Parliament in Budapest, which was notoriously nationalistic. (Not to mention that Franz Joseph absolutely abhorred working with politicians.)